# Why do we use "? super T" in java?

Tags: java, generics, super

For example, using it when using a generic Comparator - `Comparator<? super T> c`

I understand that it basically means that the Comparator will compare T and its super classes, I don't however understand the logic behind it.
Why not use "`? extends T`" ?
Or, for example, I have found a similar question of someone who asked about "`List<? super Number>`" - does it mean that the list is gonna receive Number objects and its super classes? but Number's superclass is Object, does that mean the list can receive any Object?

Comment: there may be a good question in here somewhere but it isn't narrowed down yet and from how this is posed it's not apparent you've read up on the linked question. If you can check out the linked question, then make a specific example with more code, then that might work out better.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't mean T and its super-classes. It means T and its sub-classes.
So no, the list cannot receive any Object, it can receive any sub-class of Number.

```
List<? super Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
Integer i = 23;
Double d = 3.14;
Object o = new Object();
numbers.add(i);
numbers.add(d);
numbers.add(o); // compilation error
```

`Integer` and `Double` both extend `Number`. They are sub-classes of `Number`. So they can be added to the list of numbers.

`Number` is a sub-class of `Object`. If you look at the source code, it does not explicitly extend anything (although it does implement `Serializable`). That means that its super-class is `Object`. We cannot add an Object to the numbers list.

```
Object o2 = 300;
numbers.add(o2);    // compilation error
numbers.add((Number) o2);   // no compilation error once we cast it
```

In fact, we can add an `Object` if it is a `Number`. Of course, all `Number`s are `Object`s, although not all `Object`s are `Number`s. However, if it was declared as an `Object`, then we will first have to cast it to a `Number`.

Comment: Can you add code example which will show what you mean? For now either your answer is unclear (at least for me) or wrong.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been 'it can receive any sub-class of Number' not 'it can receive any sub-class of List'.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "receive" here? Really, short compilable and executable example would be nice here.